# What is the purpose of this inside functions?

Tags: javascript, function, label

Javascript compiles this code **without** error:

```
function test() {
    property: true;
    alert('testing');
}
test(); // Shows message 'testing'
alert(test.property); // Shows 'undefined'
```

Is the content of *property* accessible in any way?

If not, what is the purpose of accepting this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`property` is not a property here. It's a label-- something you could use with `break` or `continue`. You could reformat the code you have like this:

```
function test() {
    property: 
        true;
        alert('testing');
}
```

You're not actually referencing the label, and the thing that comes after it (true) is just a no-op statement, so nothing happens when it executes. The function only meaningfully contains an alert statement.

---

You seem to be confusing an object literal with a function definition. You could create an *object* with properties like this:

```
var test = {
    property: true;
};
```

You might also be confusing it with a couple other patterns. Let us know what you're trying to accomplish for more info.

Comment: Right, I have used it as a label. I was not trying to accomplish anything specific here, I just noticed that is valid syntax and thought there might be a new trick here. Thanks.

Comment: @mykhal why would you think that?

Answer (score 0):

```
 test = function() {
    this.property = true;
    alert('testing');
}
var test = new test(); // Shows message 'testing'
alert(test.property); // Shows 'true'
```

'this' refers in this case to the function it is inside.

```
this.property = true;
```

You have to assign an instantiated function to a variable in order to use it:

```
var test = new test();
```